# Reading OpenGL Shader Language from .glsl File

Tags: c++, opengl, file-io, glsl

I am trying to read shader strings from a file; however, I faced with a problem at `glShaderSource()` function line. As you know, `glShaderSource()` takes `const char**`, and I have to declare `char *` for reading from the file. So, I am using casting to convert types.

If I use `const_cast<const char **>`, the shape appears; however, it has wrong color (It should be orange not white).
If I use `reinterpret_cast<const char**>`, I get a `Access violation reading location 0x73726576` error in running time.

So, how can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Platform: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010

Code Lines:

#### File: `shader.glsl`

```
#version 330

in vec3 vp;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4( vp, 1.0);
}
```

main():

```
/* FILE READING */
FILE* shaderFile = fopen( "shader.glsl ", "r");
int fileSize = 0;
char* vertex_shader = NULL;

//Getting File Size
fseek( shaderFile, 0, SEEK_END );
fileSize = ftell( shaderFile );
rewind( shaderFile );

//Reading From File
vertex_shader = (char*)malloc( sizeof( char) * (fileSize+1) );
fread( vertex_shader, sizeof( char ), fileSize, shaderFile );
vertex_shader[ fileSize] = '\0';
fclose( shaderFile );



//Shader definition - If I used this format, it works.
/*const char* vertex_shader = "#version 330\n"
                            "in vec3 vp;"
                            "void main(){"
                            "gl_Position = vec4( vp, 1.0);"
                            "}";*/


    //If I use const char* vertex_shader above, it appears orange.
const char* fragment_shader = "#version 330\n"
                              "out vec4 frag_colour;"
                              "void main () {"
                              "  frag_colour = vec4(0.7, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0);"
                              "}";

//Shader compiling
unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
    //The shape appears but not orange
glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, const_cast<const char **>(&vertex_shader) , NULL );
//glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, reinterpret_cast<const char**>(vertex_shader) , NULL ); //Gives error

glCompileShader( vertexShader );

unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
glShaderSource( fragmentShader, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
glCompileShader( fragmentShader );

//Shader program
unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader( shaderProgram, fragmentShader );
glAttachShader( shaderProgram, vertexShader );
glLinkProgram( shaderProgram );

//Drawing
while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glUseProgram( shaderProgram );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers( window);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: `glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&vertex_shader, NULL);`  ?

Comment: `error C2664: 'void (GLuint,GLsizei,const GLchar **,const GLint *)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'char **' to 'const GLchar **'`

Comment: The error is because of the `const`ness.

Comment: It is Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Refresh the page and test the suggestion of my first comment. It has been updated.

Comment: `glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&vertex_shader, NULL);` still white

Comment: Ok, but I have a feeling that you forgot to set the value for the variable `gl_FragColor`, which is responsible for the color of the pixel.

Comment: It is at `const char* fragment_shader` line below `fclose( shaderFile );`. Currently, it is not reading from another file.

Comment: @karlphillip: That is not necessary in GLSL 1.30+. The declaration of `out vec4 frag_colour;` in the fragment shader takes care of writing to a color buffer. A matching call to `glBindFragDataLocation (...)` would certainly be a nice thing to have, but generally that variable will default to *draw buffer* ***0***.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks. I haven't had the opportunity to write shaders for devices that deal with GLSL 1.20+.

Answer (score 6):

Pass the **address** of the array to the function:

```
glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&vertex_shader, NULL);
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for updating the code in the question. If your program compiles, doesn't crash but the shaders still don't work, it's time to investigate if the GLSL compiler returned any errors! After each call to `glCompileShader()` write something like the following to display any problems that occurred during compilation:

```
// This checks for errors upon compiling the Vertex Shader
GLint _compiled = 0;
glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &_compiled);
if (!_compiled)
{
   GLint length;
   GLchar* log;
   glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
   log = new GLchar[length];
   glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, length, &length, log);
   std::cerr << "!!! Compile log = " << log << std::endl;
   delete log;
   return;
}
```

Comment: `const char* fragment_shader = "#version 330\n"
                  "out vec4 frag_colour;"
                  "void main () {"
                  "  frag_colour = vec4(0.7, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0);"
                  "}";`

I have already had these lines in `main()`, and I am passing the address as you wrote but, it does not change anything.

Comment: If I do not read the shader from the file, and declare vertex_shader in main() as const char*, it works, and the shape appears orange. So, there is no problem with fragment_shader.
Firstly, I wrote it using only const char*, and it worked.

Comment: Listen, we don't see your code using `fragment_shader` because all you shared with us was the loading and compilation of the vertex shader. So as far as I can tell from the code, the variable `fragment_shader` is not really being used for anything and therefore shouldn't be affecting the end result. I'm glad to hear I've helped you fix the vertex problem. Good luck!

Comment: After `glCompileShader( vertexShader );` line, I copy-pasted the `GLint _compiled = 0...` lines. It enters the `if-statement` and creates a log that contains `0x00a83ce0 "0(7) error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>""`

Comment: @ciyo: That happens when you pass a zero-length shader. For whatever reason, the first byte of the address you are passing seems to be **'\0'**, and you have told OpenGL that it is a null-terminated string by passing `NULL` for the length. Perhaps the extra whitespace at the end of your file name is somehow to blame? ***"shader.glsl "***

Comment: You know, `fread()` returns the amount of elements successfully read. It's a good idea to print this information to the screen and guarantee that the application is in fact reading something from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

The `shaderSource` functiont takes a `char **` so take your `char *` and just use the `&` operator on it instead of trying to just cast it.

Comment: When I do that, it gives an `error C2664: 'void (GLuint,GLsizei,const GLchar **,const GLint *)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'char **' to 'const GLchar **'`

Comment: Declare your shader string as `GLchar *` instead then.

Comment: @ciyo buddy, come on the error is like telling you what is wrong and what you need to do. It's saying that your `GLchar**` needs to be `const` ... `const GLchar**`