# GLSL Shaders do not effect render result

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm following [this](http://open.gl/) tutorial, just starting drawing polygons. I have this problem though: the content of my shader sources doesn't matter. Here's relevant code:

*main.c*:

```
float vertices[] = {
     0.0,    0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5, -0.5
};

GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
char *vertsource = loadsource("vert.glsl");
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertsource, NULL);
free(vertsource);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);

GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
char *fragsource = loadsource("frag.glsl");
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragsource, NULL);
free(fragsource);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
//Only necesary if multiple outputs:
//glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

//0 is the position input for vert shader
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

*vert.glsl*:

```
#version 150

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

*frag.glsl*:

```
#version 150

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
        outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        //Alternative line:
        //outColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

As you can see, the code is very similar to the tutorial. However, it doesn't matter whether I use the line `outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` or `outColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` in the fragment shader, I always get this output:

[image: OpenGL output]

As long as the shader sources compile, I can execute and get this result. I don't even have to return anything, it'll still render the same. If I add or subtract the x or y value of `position` in the vert shader, I get the same result. If I make a syntax error, the program crashes as soon as opengl tries to compile, but it doesn't seem to matter what it compiles so long as it does.

If it helps, I'm running Debian with an NVIDIA graphics card and NVIDIA drivers. `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns "4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.117". I'm using freeglut as a render context.

Comment: How about filling `gl_FragColor` instead?

Comment: I don't get any change. There's no mention of a built in `gl_FragColor` output [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Outputs) either.

Comment: I can view stuff from https://www.shadertoy.com

Comment: Invoke `glUseProgram()` right before the `glBegin()` (or equivalent) call. Are you doing that?

Comment: I'm not using the deprecated fixed-pipe, so my draw function is glDrawArrays(). Putting glUseProgram in my render loop, before glDrawArrays (or after) doesn't change the result.

Comment: I suspect you have an error while [compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20754089/176769) or linking the shaders. You can call `glGetShaderiv()` to assist you on that.

Comment: @FelixTyson: glBegin/glEnd has nothing to do with fixed vs programmable pipeline. glBegin/glEnd is immediate mode vs. glDrawElements/glDrawArrays is using vertex arrays. The pipeline used is completely orthogonal to the method used to specify the vertex attributes.

Comment: @FelixTyson I think it's time to click on the checkbox near my answer, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment I made earlier pointed out the problem:

> I suspect you have an error while [compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20754089/176769) or linking the shaders. You can call glGetShaderiv() to assist you on that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out there was an error in shader compilation. I was using `(location = #)` without including the line `#extension GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location : enable` in my shader.